# Google Chrome 2FA: combining the Authenticator extension with the Secure Shell extension

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, google-chrome-extensions, authentication, remote-connection

I am sshing into a remote server using Chrome and the Secure Shell extension. This server asks for a 2FA code and a password on every login. I use the Authenticator extension to copy and paste a 2FA code in. Is there some way to automate this?

Authenticator extension: https://authenticator.cc/

Secure shell extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd?hl=en

Comment: So what exactly is your question? It sounds like you need to write your own Chrome extension that does both 2FA and is a SSH client.  How that is accomplished is beyond the scope of Super User.

Comment: @Ramhound is that really the only possible solution? I just need to pass data from one chrome extension to another. It seems like this should be possible with some kind of simple script that does not require building my own SSH client...

Comment: I would guess that scripting between extensions isn't trivial, especially inside Chrome, which has been on a path of actively limiting the scope and available functions of extensions for some time. Ramhound is probably right. Regardless, what have you tried and what research have you done? If scripting can bridge between extensions, surely this has been documented somewhere. If these extensions in particular can be interacted with programmatically, this also would be documented.

Comment: You are right that it is difficult to scrape the contents of a Chrome extension. I have tried grabbing it externally using programs like AutoHotKey, but I haven't been able to automate the whole thing. 

Maybe there's some solution already out there though? My real goal is to find a terminal emulator in my web browser that I can use to ssh to a remote server without needing to put in my password and 2fa every time I start a new session. At least with PuTTY I am able to make it share credentials so that I only need to put in my password on the first session, but PuTTY isn't web-based.

Comment: To people who come to this thread later: I am having great success just sshing using WSL2/ubuntu on Windows, which thanks to ssh config can share the connection among many different sessions. My initial hope was actually to share a terminal in the browser across multiple machines synced via workona, but that doesn't seem very likely to work out currently. But instead, now all my machines access the same server using their own linux terminal, and each just attaches to the same `screen` session, so that satisfies my requirements.